# Including Punjabi Characters in Share Option Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, share

I am displaying punjabi characters using WebAkharSlim font. I want to use share Intent in android to show punjabi characters. Is it possible for me to include font in share intent i.e. sharing content in Whatsapp , Facebook ,SMS?

Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the UTF-8 characters encoding, so you can use any characters, including punjabi characters.

To use special characters in a URL, you need to encode them, see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/1440076) on how to do that.